# .htaccess = rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to get this working and I have followed several guides.

My URL are similar to the following :

```
127.0.0.1/schools/location/north/

127.0.0.1/schools/location/south/
```

When I access them I want to show the following in the URL Bar.

```
127.0.0.1/schools/location/
```

I know this will cause a redirect and there is a valid file in /location.

I've tried the following in the `north` folder:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /$1 [L,R]
```

But it doesn't do anything, I've confirmed mod_rewrite is enabled.

Can some advise how I should be doing this.

Thanks

Comment: the .htaccess is in the north folder. I want to remove the last folder from the url purely for aesthetic reasons.  NOT my choice... I've been asked if it can be done.

Comment: .htaccess should be in `127.0.0.1/schools/location/` and removing last folders will remove some part of your URL. Now you decide whether it is fine or not

Comment: adding it to the .htaccess in location, doesn't work, I get redirected to `127.0.0.1/northern`

Comment: To make it work in `location/.htaccess` use this rule: `RewriteRule ^(north|south) /location/ [L,R]`